# PrintDocument images on 203 dpi require dithering

Tags: c#, printing, barcode, gdi

I am having a problem when printing a label using the `PrintDocument` class. I am trying to print an image which happens to be a barcode. This image is generated using the code found [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Forums/Edit.aspx?fid=470627&floc=/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library)

The problem I am experiencing is that when printing the image on a printer with a dpi of 203, the edge of the bars are blurry. I assume this is caused by the dithering on the pritner as the image is trying to print between 2 of the dots on the print head.

I have tried scaling the barcode before generating the image, but this has no effect.

```
public void Print()
{
   PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument
   {
       DefaultPageSettings =
       {
           Landscape = label.Landscape,
           PaperSize = label.PaperSize
       },
       OriginAtMargins = true,
       PrinterSettings = { PrinterName = "PrinterName" },
       PrintController = new StandardPrintController()
   };

   printDocument.PrintPage += On_PrintPage;
   printDocument.Print();
}

private void On_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    DrawBarcode(_elements[0], e.Graphics);
}

private DrawBarcode(IElement labelElement, Graphics graphics)
{
    float xTranslate = (labelElement.X/96)*Dpi - ((hardMarginX/100)*Dpi );
    float yTranslate = (labelElement.Y/96)*Dpi - ((hardMarginY/100)*Dpi );

    //Call to baroode library
    Image barcodeImage = labelElement.GetBarcodeImage((int) ((labelElement.Width/96)*Dpi ), (int) ((labelElement.Height/96)*Dpi ));

    graphics.TranslateTransform(xTranslate, yTranslate);
    graphics.DrawImage(barcodeImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, barcodeImage.Width, barcodeImage.Height));
    graphics.ResetTransform();
}
```

The `IElement` object is just a class which holds information about the location and size of an element which will be printed on the label.

I thought that generating the with the size `(labelElement.Width/96)*Dpi` where `Dpi = 203` would have solved the problem. Before this change the dpi was always 300 as this is what GDI uses as its units. This change has not helped in the barcode image clarity and has caused problem where the elements are not appearing where they should.

Is there anyway I can print clear images (specifically barcodes) on a 203 dpi printer from the `PrintDocument` class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a stale question- For anyone else that trips into this:

You can access DitherType in [Win32_PrinterConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
but it seems read-only.

The easier way to go around it is to actually set dithering to NONE in the printer preferences through windows ui.